# Neo4j embedded server in HA mode

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to use neo4j embedded server in HA mode with spring data neo4j.I am getting error of class loading. i have put all the jars. 
I am trying to use neo4j embedded server in HA mode with spring data neo4j.I am getting error of class loading. i have put all the jars.

```
    Running Grails application
        | Error 2014-10-18 17:27:46,878 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator - [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to perform post initialization config: file:./grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml
        Message: org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase
        Line | Method
        ->> 366 | run in java.net.URLClassLoader$1

        | 355 | run in ''
        | 354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
        | 425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
        | 262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
        | 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
        | 615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker

    and my xml configuration is

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="neo4j"></context:component-scan>
        <bean id="haDatabase" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase"
            destroy-method="shutdown">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="target/db" />
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <map>
                    <entry key="ha.server_id" value="1" />
                    <entry key="ha.server" value="localhost:6001" />
                    <entry key="ha.coordinators" value="localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="haDatabase"  base-package="neo4j"/>
        <bean id="config"
            class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.DataGraphNamespaceHandlerTests$Config" />
         <neo4j:repositories base-package="neo4jRepository" />

and i have dependencies are
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.2.0.RELEASE"
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-enterprise:2.1.5"
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-ha:2.1.5"
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-cluster:jar:2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to an API change in Neo4j 1.9 you cannot instantiate `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase` directly. Instead you should use `HighlyAvailableGraphdatabaseFactory`. Please see one of my gists showing how you can use it: https://gist.github.com/sarmbruster/6222698

Answer (score 0):

This example may also help you with the java code. (Neo4j 2.1.2)

https://github.com/Jotschi/neo4j-ha-example

snippet:

```
    GraphDatabaseBuilder builder = new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory().newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder(DB_LOCATION);

    builder.setConfig(ClusterSettings.server_id, SERVER_ID);
    builder.setConfig(HaSettings.ha_server, "localhost:6001");
    builder.setConfig(HaSettings.slave_only, Settings.FALSE);
    builder.setConfig(ClusterSettings.cluster_server, "localhost:5001");
    builder.setConfig(ClusterSettings.initial_hosts, "localhost:5001,localhost:5002");

    graphDb = builder.newGraphDatabase();
```